# Member variable gets a random value even that I initialize it in constructor - why?

Tags: c++, synchronization, pthreads, monitor

I'm trying to write classic producer - consumer program with use of Monitor class provided by my teacher and pthreads library. I think that I've got logic behind my simple algorithm right, but in order for it to work I need to keep track of how many elements are currently in the buffer. I don't know why, but variable responsible for that value is getting random value, even that I initialize it (along with 2 other variables) to zero in constructor. Could anyone point the mistake i make?
 (Monitor library from teacher provides enter() and leave() functions that make sure only one thread is accessing data between them and Condition class, which provides condition variables which you can perform wait() and signal() on - like in normal [monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)).)

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "mybuffer.h"

void* client (void* parameters)
{
  MyBuffer *p = (MyBuffer *) parameters;
  char whatsinthebox;
  int loop_counter = 0;
  while(loop_counter < 5) {
    printf("Client loop nr: %d\n",loop_counter);
    whatsinthebox = p->Pop();
    printf("Product recieved: %c\n", whatsinthebox);
    sleep(5);
    loop_counter++;

  }
}

void* producer (void* parameters)
{
  MyBuffer *p = (MyBuffer *) parameters;
  int loop_counter = 0;
  char product = 'X';
  while(loop_counter<20) {
    printf("Producer loop nr: %d\n",loop_counter);
    p->Push(product);
    printf("Product inserted: %c\n", product);
    sleep(1);
    loop_counter++;
  }
}


int main()
{
  MyBuffer *just_buffer = new MyBuffer();
  pthread_t thread1_id;
  pthread_t thread2_id;

  pthread_create (&thread1_id, NULL, &producer, &just_buffer);
  pthread_create (&thread2_id, NULL, &client, &just_buffer);

  pthread_join (thread1_id, NULL);
  pthread_join (thread2_id, NULL);

  delete just_buffer;
  return 0;
}
```

mybuffer.h:

```
#ifndef MYBUFFER_H
#define MYBUFFER_H

#define MAX_ELEMENTS 9
#define BUFFER_SIZE (MAX_ELEMENTS+1)

#include "monitor.h"

class MyBuffer: public Monitor
{
private:

  int data_in, data_out, elements_count;
  char data[BUFFER_SIZE];
  Condition full, empty;

public:

  MyBuffer ()
  {
    enter();
    data_in = data_out = 0;
    elements_count = 0;
    leave();
  }

  int Push(char c)
  {
    enter();
    printf("Elements count before conditon in Push: %d\n",elements_count);
    printf("data_in before conditon in Push: %d\n",data_in);
    printf("data_out count before conditon in Push: %d\n",data_out);
    if (elements_count == MAX_ELEMENTS)
      wait(full); // queue full - can't push
    data[data_in] = c;
    data_in = (data_in + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
    elements_count++;
    if (elements_count == 1)
      signal(empty);
    leave();
    return 0; // no errors
  }

  char Pop()
  {
    char value;
    enter();    
    if (elements_count == 0)
      wait(empty); // queue empty - nothing to pop
    value = data[data_out];
    data_out = (data_out + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
    elements_count--;
    if (elements_count == MAX_ELEMENTS - 1)
      signal(full);
    leave();
    return value;
  }
};

#endif
```

Comment: My error was in passing 4th argument to pthread_create as reference - when it was already a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

My error was in passing 4th argument to pthread_create as reference - when it was already a pointer.

So I should either passi it without & like this:

```
pthread_create (&thread1_id, NULL, &producer, just_buffer);
```

Or just define normal object of my class instead of pointer like this:

```
MyBuffer just_buffer;
```